# Need to convert SVG, EPS or PDF to Photoshop custom shape

Tags: pdf, svg, adobe-photoshop, shapes, eps

I have an object in vector in SVG, EPS and PDF formats. I need any of them to be imported to Adobe Photoshop as a custom vector shape. How can I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Open in Illustrator; copy vector; paste as paths in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import any vector file into Photoshop it will scale inside Photoshop but when you save it as a jpg, png, tiff, ... it will be rasterized.

But if you want it anyway in Photoshop, just copy the image in it (if that doesnt work try opening it with Illustrator and save it as a vector). Pick Shape layer and it will be an editable vector (Smart Object) inside your PSD, untill you save it as another extension.

Answer (score 6):

For batch conversion of SVGs to CSH, you can use the [IcoMoon app](https://icomoon.io/app). First, import your SVG, then choose the **Generate SVG & More** button at the bottom of the app. Press the **Preferences** button and check the **Photoshop Shapes (CSH)** option.

Comment: finally an answer that's free and works

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe Illustrator (or CorelDRAW or Macromedia Freehand), you can do this.
I just found out the answer and I thought I'd share the link with you even if the question dates a bit ^^'
Here is the tutorial: [link](http://www.indezine.com/products/photoshop/shapesfromillustrator.html)
Thanks a million for whoever wrote that tutorial!